# Why are there every day so many questions in the "new question list" which are years old but recently modified?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering why there are so many "modified" questions in the list? 
 In my opinion that's kinda annoying and makes it difficult/annoying to find the real new questions. 
 Wouldn't it be better not showing the very old but modified questions in that list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's either an automated process or a human's edit which bumps old posts to the front page - so they can be improved, get new answers, updated content, or sometimes to be closed as no longer on topic.

You can always set your entry page to just show new ones - you must have your view on Active rather than New